How to tell iterm2 to use emacs mode, not vi mode
I've recently switched from Hyper terminal (no longer maintained) to iterm2.
I'm surprised that iterm2 seems to be using vi mode: instead of going to start and end of line when I press ctrl+a/ctrl+e it emits literal ^A and ^E.
I don't remember ever configuring vi mode on purpose. iterm2's configuration GUI overwhelms me.
I've tested running zsh in factory mode (zsh -f), and even there iterm2 uses vi mode.
In contrast, when I use Hyper or the inbuilt terminal, zsh is in default readline mode. How can I fix this? I've gone through iterm2 documentation and issue tracker and couldn't find anything.
Interestingly, when I run zsh -f in inbuilt Terminal, it is in vi mode.
Similar question over at superuser, which has been open for 10 years without answer: https://superuser.com/questions/840134/unintentional-vi-mode-in-iterm-on-mac

It has nothing to do with Terminal vs iTerm and everything to do with what the shell running inside them is configured to do.  The terminal emulator is not providing the line editor, the shell is.
From the zsh documentation:

If one of the VISUAL
or EDITOR environment variables contain the string 'vi' when the shell starts up then it will be 'viins',
otherwise it will be 'emacs'.  bindkey's -e and -v options provide a convenient way to override this default
choice.

Regarding your behavior differences, look at what combination of your shell startup files is being read by the shell when it is started by the terminal emulator.  One or another of them is most likely loading the shell as a login shell, while another of them is not.
Also, the phrase "readline mode" is meaningless.  Put bashin vi mode and it's still using readline for the line editor.

I still don't know why iterm2 behaves differently from Terminal and Hyper but here's a fix:
Append bindkey -e on a new line to your ~/.zshrc.
This explicitly tells zsh to use emacs/readline keybindings.
I do set export EDITOR=vim in my ~/.zshrc so that could be why zsh thinks I want to use vi bindings on the command line. Still very strange that the behavior is different between iterm2 and Terminal.

Apologies for the bother, but...  Did your question concern how vi/vim handle ctrl+a/ctrl+e when running from iTerm2?

@Seamus no I was only concerned about the command line part, the prompt
